# D arbitrary code at compile time

Tags: d, dmd, ctfe

I've heard D can execute arbitrary user code at compile time. Is this true? Could someone give an example (particularly when compilation never terminates)? What this feature is for? Also if that's so is there a way to disable this with some compiler option (compiler is dmd)?

Comment: not arbitrary code, only pure functions can be done at compile time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's partially true.  D has [compile time function execution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_time_function_execution), i.e. it has the ability of executing functions at compile time.  But such functions are required to be both **portable** and **free of side effects**.

You will find an in-depth explanation in the [official documentation of the D language](http://dlang.org/function.html#interpretation).

Comment: I would add too that while you can put the compiler into an infinite loop if you wanted to, it can't do anything more malicious than that; it can't overwrite files or send spam on the network or anything like that. In your own program, compile time execution is opt-in so you can just not use it if you don't want to, and in other people's programs, I'd just say if the compile is taking unreasonably long just hit ctrl+c to forcibly stop it.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe it could make the executable unreasonably large by bloat

Comment: @ratchetfreak sometimes "bloated" programs are more useful than super-compact stuff which does everything on runtime, and besides, it can be controlled by the (library) programmer, so its a super useful tool